# abandonment patent

Tags: patent-applications, abandonment

I had a patent. But patent with no reason now abandonment patent. Legal department directed patent this way. Now someone else made my idea and it is a 3 billion dollars annual sales. what can I do? Can I ask for rights? even there is an abandonment ?

Comment: Please add details like - what country, did the inventor or a company they work for own the patent, etc. Also, to keep the question open you should change it from being about you to a hypothetical person. “If an inventor . . .” Would be a way to start a hypothetical question.

Comment: I appreciate that English may not be your primary language. In addition to George White's comment, if you really believe this is potentially a 3 billion dollar licensing opportunity, then you owe it to yourself to consult with an actual patent attorney. A single meeting may be enough to answer your questions.